# Netsuite Integration help

Tags: netsuite

I'm just starting to look into how I can make calls to Netsuite's Suitetalk API from within Salesforce. Ideally I'd like to have a panel on one of our layouts that would display a Visualforce page that calls a controller that would communicate with Suitetalk and pull back the information that I need.

I need help with making the call out to Suitetalk and parsing the response. So for example when I am viewing one of our account records in Salesforce this panel that communicates with Netsuite would display related contract info from Netsuite. Our requirements are purely read-only for now.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some sample code for calling Suitetalk? I haven't been able to find much so far on how to do this through apex code.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with SuiteTalk so unfortunately can't help much more than pull a few bits together.

Looks like they have a WSDL http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml which you should be able to consume in apex to create a client stub to start out with your integration

There's some more information on using APEX generation from a WSDL [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_wsdl_to_package.htm&language=en)

If you've got Apex experience then you should be able to integrate using the generated classes and a custom visualforce page using the standard controller for whatever object you want your page to be on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I already tried what you suggested but unfortunately I got the following error: 

"Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Found schema import from location https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2015_1_0/core.xsd. External schema import not supported"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to code it a good alternative would be lightning connect. maybe interesting to have a look at that.
http://www.odata.org/blog/netsuite-salesforce-lightning-connect/